# I got locked out of my switch

Tags: cisco, switch, packet-tracer, cisco-commands

I am currently practicing on cisco packet tracer, so I used the command " enable password 5 cisco"
then I leave the global configuration mode to the user mode and try to go to privilege mode using the "enable" command, and I am prompted for a password which I set but when I type in 'cisco' as I earlier set. I keep getting bad secret message

How do I go about this or did I set the password wrong ?

Comment: The best practice is never use the `enable password` command, but instead use the `enable secret` command.

Answer (score 2):

A type 5 encrypted password is set by `enable secret 5 [encryptedpassword]` - you've likely set the (unencrypted) password to "5 cisco".